# Isotropy group invariant pluriharmonic function on bounded symmetric domain is constant?

Tags: real-analysis, complex-analysis

If $f$ is a pluriharmonic function on a bounded symmetric domain $D$, i.e. $\partial\bar{\partial}f=0$ on $D$, moreover, it is invariant under the isotropy group
$K_p=\{\phi\in Aut(D): \phi(p)=p\}$, where $p\in \bar{D}$, i.e. $f\circ \phi=f$ for any $\phi\in K_p$, is $f$ a constant ?

Because when I read a paper, the author claims the $K_p$-invariant Kahler potential of Bergman metric is unique, so I want to prove the uniqueness. see the attachment.[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/evSY6.png)